# Google Earth Engine: Using MULTIPROBABILITY output mode in classifier

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to perform a land cover classification task on Landsat 8 images using the RandomForest classifier in Google Earth Engine. I'd like to obtain an output where for each class I get a separate band with the corresponding posterior class probabilities. According to the [Google Earth Engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-classifier-setoutputmode), this should be possible through the 'MULTIPROBABILITY' output mode.

However, when I try to use this output mode, the result is a single-band image. I have tried this will most other classifiers and always get a single band result.
Below is the code snippet:

```
// Define bands and classifier
var bands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B10', 'B11', 'NDVI'];
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({
  numberOfTrees: 100,
  minLeafPopulation: 3,
  bagFraction: 0.5,
  seed: 0,
}).setOutputMode('MULTIPROBABILITY').train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'classCode',
  inputProperties: bands
});

// Classify the image
var probabilities = composite.select(bands).classify(classifier);

// Print band names and types to the console
print('Band names: ', probabilities.bandNames());
print('Band types: ', probabilities.bandTypes());
```

Here, 'training' is a feature collection of training samples, and 'composite' is a cloud-free image composite of Landsat 8 images. When I inspect the band names and types of the 'probabilities' image, I get a single band.

I was wondering if I'm using the 'MULTIPROBABILITY' output mode correctly, or if there is another way to obtain the class probabilities for each class separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I was able to find the solution. The output of a classifier with multiprobability output type is an array band.

So, after classifying the data, the output must be flattened:

```
// Classify the image
var probabilities = composite.select(bands).classify(classifier);

// Extract the probabilities for each cover type
var probabilities = classified.arrayFlatten([['bare', 'grass', 'trees', 'uluhe']]);
```

This results in an object with each band representing the probability of class membership for every class considered!

Comment: The docs expicitly say: "MULTIPROBABILITY: The output is an array of probabilities that each class is correct ordered by classes seen".  Was that not clear enough or did you somehow miss it?

Comment: Thanks Noel for the input! I was not familiar with the array band type of object, so just expected for a stack or collection with n layers equivalent to the classes. Since I was not familiar with the array band, on inspection GEE would tell me it was a single layer, and when adding the result to the map, gee defaults to mapping the first array element without throwing a warning or error (that other array elements are present), so everything indicated to me that it was a single layer raster output.